# How can I remove a 'bad document'?

Tags: java, couchdb

I've somehow made a bad document in my database which is hanging some views. I've narrowed it down to this document:

ID: 0fd5cd9ec4814c07aab8262fbf2a563b
rev: "31-e545cf536490d353a14c507073e519cc"

However, I cannot seem to find a good way to remove the document. Using futon and fauxton just hang the browser, and using curl I seem to get why. I've somehow inserted a funky set of unicode characters '���'. When getting the document with curl, it's an endless loop of these characters. I think this issue is from a &nbsp encoding wrong which maybe is a bug on my server wrapper around couch, but regardless I can't fix it without removing this document first, it seems.

A snippet of the GET: 
    ..."1414788167464":{"Updater":"super_user","New Value":"hello������������������������...(start endless loop)

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/records/0fd5cd9ec4814c07aab8262fbf2a563b?rev=31-e545cf536490d353a14c507073e519cc
```

results in
    curl: No match.

Any suggestions for removal, or even on safely encoding text to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you see what happens when you try to update the document? You can delete a document by by updating it to  `{'_id':...,'_rev':..,"_deleted":true}`. Also with curl command try enclosing the url in "" because there is a `-` in the _rev field maybe that is why it is causing issues.

Comment: Wow -- quotes fixed the issue. Thanks! I'm now hammering out the issue with the non-breaking spaces, but it's still a little scary knowing it created this infinite-loop situation inside couch. Thanks again!